# Oracle SQL - Present row data in columns

Tags: sql, report

I'm trying to produce a report using Oracle SQL that is more user friendly. The data will be exported to Excel for the user.

I have an example table

| ID | CUSTOMER_ID | AWARD | AMOUNT | NET_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | AWARD1 | 500 | 300 |
| 2 | 1001 | AWARD3 | 600 | 250 |
| 3 | 1001 | AWARD5 | 400 | 400 |
| 4 | 1002 | AWARD1 | 500 | 500 |
| 5 | 1002 | AWARD2 | 300 | 300 |
| 6 | 1002 | AWARD3 | 300 | 300 |
| 7 | 1003 | AWARD4 | 200 | 200 |
| 8 | 1004 | AWARD3 | 300 | 300 |
| 9 | 1004 | AWARD4 | 200 | 200 |
| 10 | 1004 | AWARD5 | 400 | 400 |

What I am trying to achieve is Oracle SQL that will produce an output something along the lines of:

**RESULTS:**

```
 1. 1001|AWARD1;500;300;NULL;NULL;NULL;AWARD3;600;250;NULL;NULL;NULL;AWARD5;400;400
 2. 1002|AWARD1;500;300;AWARD2;300;300;AWARD3;600;250;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL
 3. 1003|NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;AWARD4;200;200;NULL;NULL;NULL
 4. 1004|NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;AWARD3;600;250;AWARD4;200;200;AWARD5;400;400
```

I have previously used:

```
 LISTAGG (AWARD|| ';' || AMOUNT || ';' || NET_AMOUNT||';')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID)
            AS EXAMPLE_OUTPUT
```

to list all the awards on a single row against the CUSTOMER_ID.

However this option data doesn't line up neatly enough (in Excel) as each customer has a different set of awards.

Comment: Do you know how many awards (specifically) are there in your data? Also is 'AWARD1' the real name of the award or is it just a placeholder?

Comment: use PIVOT instead e.g. https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/sql-11g-pivot.html - **OR** - consider using a pivot table in Excel instead

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that only AWARD 1 through 5 will be present , you can use the statement below which utilises oracle PIVOT and listagg. Please note that I have used a string 'NULL;NULL;NULL;' to represent an empty value which you will have to remove from your excel .

```
select customer_id, (NVL((LISTAGG (award1,';')
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY customer_id)),'NULL;NULL;NULL;') ||';'||
                    NVL((LISTAGG (award2,';')
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY customer_id)),'NULL;NULL;NULL;')||';'||
        NVL((LISTAGG (award3,';')
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY customer_id)),'NULL;NULL;NULL;') ||';'||
        NVL((LISTAGG (award4,';')
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY customer_id)),'NULL;NULL;NULL;')||';'||
        NVL((LISTAGG (award5,';')
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY customer_id)),'NULL;NULL;NULL;')||';')
                    as output
           from
(select * from customer c
pivot(
min(award||';'||amount||';'||net_amount)
  for award in('AWARD1' as AWARD1,'AWARD2' as AWARD2,'AWARD3' as AWARD3,'AWARD4' as AWARD4,'AWARD5' as AWARD5)
) order by customer_id)
 group by customer_id;
```

sqlfiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/94fef2/113